# How to find the number of different existing routes in a problem where there is a maze of interconnecting lines?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, puzzle

I had to solve this riddle from my book but so far I'm stuck at by doing several attempts and I felt it is like counting grains of sugar or some kind of sisyphean task. Can somebody help me with this?

The problem is as follows:

> Using the figure from below, find the number of different routes which
>   exist to go from point B to point A by traveling only in the
>   directions indicated, being upwards, to the left, and in upward
>   diagonals.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The existing alternatives given were:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&63\\
2.&39\\
3.&48\\
4.&56\\
5.&52\\
\end{array}$

Well for this one I'm totally lost. The only thing that I could come up with was to draw what it was the obvious choice, or in other words to draw the figure as depicted in orange line. But that was only one path that I could find. I tried to go in with another route which is colored as pear color, but that's how far I went.

[image: Sketch of the attempted solution]

Does it exist a way to solve this riddle more systematically and not just guessing or playing around with different combinations?.

An answer which would help me the most is one which could include perhaps an improved graphics or some sort of redrawing in Asymptote or any program showing a path or a way to solve this perhaps graphically if required.

I'd like somebody could help me with this question as I tried much effort and has not yet yielded results. Hence require assistance. Can somebody guide me on this?.

Comment: How do you get started if you can't use downward diagonals?

Comment: You can view this as a directed graph, and use linear algebra to [count walks in a directed graph](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~gptesler/184a/slides/184a_ch10.3slides_17-handout.pdf)

Comment: If the question was "how many ways to get from B to A", the answer would be $52$.

Comment: @Jens I'm sorry. I tried to copy my attempt from my handwritten notes, the first thing I could come up with was to draw lines between $A$ to $B$. But because I was in a rush I didn't realized that it was the other way around in other words from $B$ to $A$. Please check the edited question. Yes I noticed that downward diagonals were not allowed.

Comment: @Jens You're indeed correct, the question was find the way from $B$ to $A$ not as it was written earlier I edited the question to reflect what it was in the original source. I'm sorry because I did it in a rush. Now for the second part I don't know how you got to $52$.

Comment: @PeterKagey I'm not familiar with directed graphs but I've found [this](https://mathinsight.org/definition/directed_graph) which mentions its definition, and also in [wolfram alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectedGraph.html) and in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) I've read your reference but I don't know how would apply here. This problem was intended to be solved without the requirement of matrices to which I'm not uncomfortable but there was a time limitation for this particular riddle hence the question for a simple solution.

Comment: @PeterKagey I'm not very savvy with the knowledge to use the reference you mentioned, perhaps if you could post an example of how to use it, it would be much helpful to me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using dynamic programming. You will label each node with the number of legal paths from $B$ to that node. Initially, $B$ itself is labeled with $1$. Starting with the nodes which are closer to $B$, write label each node with the sum of the labels of its neighbors in the $\to,\searrow,\downarrow$ and $\swarrow$ directions. If there are no nodes in those direction, skip them in the sum. If you try to add up the label of an unlabeled node, first find the label of that earlier node. This works because every path to a node is preceded by a path to one of its $\to,\searrow,\downarrow,\swarrow$ neighbors. Adding the numbers of these paths gives the number of paths to the original node.

If I compute correctly, the answer is $52.$

[image]

Comment: This concept of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) is totally new for me. It took me time to understand what you did but I think I got it. Because there are limitation of characters in the comment box, I had to split my questions in the coming comments. Can you take some time to read them please?. :-)

Comment: In your graph each node has a number which indicates the number of paths allowed from $B$ to that node, am I right?. For example the one which is on the right of label $4$ says $1$, this is $1$ because the only allowed route to get there is an upward diagonal and a straight line up, so that accounts for one path, right?. Then $4$ is $1+1+2$ the other three left corners in that square.

Comment: But precaution must be taken as $5$ which is in the upper square is $4+1$ and not $4+1+1$ because there is no link between the $1$ which is in the bottom right of that square with the label numbered $5$. Is this part right?. Gee I hope to be understanding you well because at looking at this maze initially I felt dumbfounded.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell You got it!

Comment: I believe that your answer could be improved if you add zeros to the top corners on the right side of $A$ as you did below to the left side of $B$ as they indicate they're not nodes. The more I look on it, seems that this riddle wasn't that hard as it seemed to be. I'm left curious does this approach will work with this kinds of problems or should I be aware or some caveat or advise on using this what you called dynamic programming?. Since I don't know much about it, I'd like to be careful to not incur into any misunderstanding or any error.

Comment: I'm glad to know that I got what you intended to say. When it comes to graphic riddles it takes me time to catch up, so that's the reason for clarification. I also believe that your preceding comment should be upgraded to be part of your answer because this helped me to understand and confirm why you're doing what you are doing (sorry if it sounds redundant). Thanks!. :-)

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Okay added. I disagree that you should put zeroes up top. For example there are 6 paths to the upper right node. I just left them unlabeled since their counts are unneeded to find the number of paths to $A$.

Comment: Sorry. I overlooked that. Those would account for $22$ and $6$ right?. Moving from the top right next to $A$. The ones which are zeros I believe its because there is no way to get there since the only allowed moves are upwards diagonals. Was this the reason of $0$ for those to the left of $B$?. Do in this kinds of riddles should I always assign the starting point as $1$?.

Comment: There was left an unattended question regarding if does it exist any other caveat or precaution that should I have in consideration when attempting to solve similar problems?. Btw do you think my question deserves downvote? I think my attempt was not too lousy (although erroneous at first though). Probably it was due in the beginning there was an error in the way how it was written but I edited. Anyways, thanks for your help and hope you can clear my final doubts posted in this comment. :-)